# showing Segmentation fault in hacker rank

Tags: c

Below error is showing from compiler(Hackerrank c compiler).Here a is the pointer and assinged a starting address of memory block through malloc and given the input a string at runtime.Could any one help me?

```
GDB trace:
Reading symbols from solution...done.
[New LWP 4659]
Core was generated by `solution'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  main () at solution.c:22
22      if ((a[i] != a[j]) && (i >= 0 && j < n)) {
#0  main () at solution.c:22
```

and my code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    int n, k, i, j, mid;
    char *a;
    int *l;
    a = (char *)malloc((n + 1) * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%d", &n);
    scanf("%d", &k);
    scanf("%s", a);
    mid = (0 + (n - 1)) / 2;
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        i = mid;
        j = mid + 1;
        l = (int *)malloc((n / 2) * sizeof(int));
    } else {
        i = mid;
        j = mid;
        l = (int *)malloc((n / 2 + 1) * sizeof(int));
    }

    while (k != 0) {
        if ((a[i] != a[j]) && (i >= 0 && j < n)) {
            if (a[i] > a[j]) {
                a[j] = a[i];
                k--;
                i--;
                j++;
            } else {
                a[i] = a[j];
                k--;
                i--;
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%s", a);
}
```

Comment: Most probably you'll be fine by switching the order of the conditions in the `if`.

Comment: Hi, please share your code, or a smaller version allowing us to reproduce the issue easily.

Comment: I love programs that use meaningful variable names. Also scanf returns a useful value

Answer (score 4):

In `if ((a[i] != a[j]) && (i >= 0 && j < n))` the conditions are reversed. You first index `a[i]` and `a[j]` before you check that `i` and `j` are valid for indexing `a`. This means that if `i` and/or `j` were invalid, you already used them. Try reversing the order to `if ((i >= 0 && j < n) && (a[i] != a[j]))`.

edit: Other apparent issues (now that more code is posted):

- `n` is used as an argument to `malloc` before it is initialized
- you don't limit the length of `scanf("%s", a);`
- if `i` and/or `j` goes out of bounds while `k != 0`, the loop never terminates
- if `a[i] == a[j]` while `k != 0`, the loop never terminates

And the usual nitpicks:

- don't cast the return value of `malloc`
- `sizeof(char)` is always 1 by definition, multiplying by it is pointless